Space of distributions on $[0,1]^2$: weakly compact or not?
Let $X_1,X_2$ be distributions on $[0,1]$ and let $X=(X_1,X_2)$ be the joint distribution of $X_1,X_2$. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all such joint distribution $X$.
Question 1: Does $\mathcal{X}$ equals to the set of all measurable functions $f$ on $[0,1]^2$ such that $\int_{[0,1]^2} f=1$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0$ for every $(x,y)\in [0,1]$?
Question 2 (weak* compactness): Let $C_b([0,1]^2)$ be the set of all bounded continous functions on $[0,1]^2$. Does the following holds?:
For any sequences of functions $f_1,f_2,\dots \in\mathcal{X}$, there exist its sub-sequence $f_{i_1},f_{i_2},\dots$ and $f_0\in\mathcal{X}$, such that for any $g\in C_b([0,1]^2)$, we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_{i_n}\cdot g\to\int f_{0}\cdot g.$$

Question 1:
No, there need not exist such $f$. Consider the simple case of $X_1 = X_2$ random variables where $X_1$ has say, pdf $g$.
Then being equivalent to $f$ on $[0, 1]^2$ such that
$$\int_{[0, 1]^2} f = \int_0^1 \int_0^1  f(x, y) \, dx \,dy = 1$$
is saying that $(X_1, X_2)$ admits a joint pdf $f$ with respect to Lebesgue measure. This $f$ would satisfy, for Borel subsets $E \subset [0, 1]^2$,
$$\mathbb P[(X_1, X_2) \in E \,] = \int_E f(z) d\mathcal L^2 (z),$$
with $\mathcal L^2$ denoting the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
But the correct integral is
$$\mathbb P[(X_1, X_2) \in E \,] = \int_{E} g(D^{-1}(z)) \, d (D_* \mathcal L^1)(z),$$
where $D: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$ is the diagonal map $z \to (z, z)$ and $D_* \mu$ is the pushforward measure of a measure $\mu$ by $D$.
The integration measures are mutually singular, and so cannot be converted to each other by multiplication by any Radon-Nikodym derivative, hence your statement doesn’t hold.
Intuitively, $(X_1, X_2)$ is supposed on the “lower dimensional” diagonal $\Delta := \{(x, x) \, | \,  x \in [0, 1]\}$.
Question 2:
On the other hand, the space of joint probability distributions is weak-star compact, and you can find a proof in any standard introductory probability text, eg Billingsley or Durrett.

Thanks for your answer! So, does the set of all measurable functions on $[0,1]^2$ a subset of $\mathcal{X}$? And does $\mathcal{X}$ equals to the space of all probability distributions on $[0,1]^2$?

Yes to both! The set of all measurable functions as you wrote has a natural interpretation as the set of distributions admitting a joint density. @tomjerry

Thank you, River! And thus, is it wrong to view $\mathcal{X}$ as a subset of $L_1([0,1]^2)$ since there exist the counterexample as you give in your answer?

That is also right I believe. @tomjerry

May I ask a question: For a distribution which is supposed on a 0-measured subset of $[0,1]^2$, how could we calculate its integer on a measureable subset of $[0,1]^2$? i.e., let $f:[0,1]^2\to [0,1]$ be a measureable function with $\int f=0$. Could we consider the distribution as something like $f(x,y)/(\int f)$ and calculate its integer on $[0,0.5]\cdot [0,0.5]$? Thank you a very much for your time!

Sorry, what do yoy mean by calculate it’s integer? @tomjerry

@tomjerry You have already asked this as a new question, please don't use comment threads to ask new questions.

I mean for a PDF $g$ on $[0,1]^2$, we can calculate its integer $\int_A g$ on the measurable subset $A$--and this value shows the proportion of $g$ distributed on $A$ compared to on $[0,1]^2$. For $f$ with $\int f>0$, the distribution (with respect to $f$) 's integer on $[0,0.5]\cdot [0,0.5]$ is just $\int_[0,0.5]\cdot [0,0.5] f/\int f$. However, when $\int f=0$ (as your example), could we do a samilar thing to know the proportion of $f$ distributed on $[0,0.5]\cdot [0,0.5]$ compared to on $[0,1]^2$? Thanks very much! @NateRiver
